# C# - El valor no puede ser null (parámetro 'connectionString') .NET 6

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net, migration

Uso .Net 6 y cuando quiero ejecutar mi primera migración, recibo este error:

> El valor no puede ser null. (Parámetro 'connectionString')

Mi appsettings.json

```
    {
  "Logging": {
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=MSI;Initial Catalog=tiendalibro;Integrated Security=True"
    },
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Y el siguiente es mi metodo en Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ContextoLibreria>(options => options.UseSqlServer("DefaultConnection"));
```

Comment: En el `options.UseSqlServer` intenta reemplazar toda la cadena de DefaultConnection por tus configuraciones de conexión de forma manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta reemplazar este método:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ContextoLibreria>(options => options.UseSqlServer("DefaultConnection"));
```

Por este:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ContextoLibreria>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Por otro lado, también veo que estás poniendo la cadena de conexión dentro del `logging`, intenta ponerla debajo de `AllowedHosts: "*"` :

```
     {
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
      "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=MSI;Initial Catalog=tiendalibro;Integrated Security=True"
    },
}
```

Comment: Amigo!!!! funciono, muchas gracias.
Ya tenia un buen tiempo intentando arreglar eso.

Comment: Si la respuesta te sirvió, te pido que la marques como aceptada, para que así puedas ayudar a otras personas con el mismo problema

Answer (score 2):

Es porque tienes mal configurado tu appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=MSI;Initial Catalog=tiendalibro;Integrated Security=True"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

y en **`Program.cs`** llamas tu conexion

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ContextoLibreria>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});
```